# MailApp.sendEmail sending mail from a specific alias

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way in which one can send a mail using a specific user mentioned alias via the MailApp.sendEmail function.

For example : The recipient should see that the mail is coming from an XYZ@gmail.com instead of my actual log in mail ID:

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If its any similar to the way sending emails in php works then you should be able to set the header which almost all email clients I have seen accept it as the source including iphones and outlook:

```
$to = 'guyImsendingto@gmail.com';
     $title = "A ghost from the future";
     $desc = "I have sent an email from the future, from me, to me. Listen, we must not go out this weekend!! Trust us, stay in and away from .. THAT PLACE";
     $headers = 'From:XYZ@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
     mail($to, $title, $desc, $headers);
     echo "Done";
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, I am new to coding in general so pardon my ignorance but I don't believe the MailApp.sendEmail function supports a header parameter. Source : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app
Do let me know if I am missing out on something.